# iOS UiLocalNotification formatting

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am adding local notifications to my current project and I noticed something weird. What I am doing is displaying warnings when a piece of hardware has a low battery. When the app is in the foreground (and I replace the notification with an alert view) the string displays fine. However when the app is in the background my percentile sign disappears.

```
    @"%@ has less than %i%% battery left!"
```

is the string that I am using. In the alert view it will display something like "X has less than 10% battery left!" but the background notification displays "X has less than 10battery left!"

Has anyone encountered that before?

edit (adding code snippet)

```
UILocalNotification *lc = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
lc.fireDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
lc.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has less than %i%% battery left!", name, percentage];

lc.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
lc.applicationIconBadgeNumber = lc.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:lc];
```

Where name is a NSString and percentage is an int

Comment: can you please display your code for setting notification

Comment: @freenalcer I posted the snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue in my simulator also and also I fixed the issue.

Use:

```
@"%@ has less than %i %%%% battery left!"
```

**or**

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has less than %i %@ battery left!",@"Your App",7,@"%%"]
```

Instead of:

```
@"%@ has less than %i%% battery left!"
```

Comment: but why you need to use 4 time mod sign?

Comment: This is in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

@freenalcer - The reason you have to use 4 percent signs is because you're substituting 2 percents for one, but you have to properly format the substitution string by escaping each percent symbol.

Answer (score 5):

I found out that using the unicode character equivalent will make it work in both the alert view and notification. I changed my string to:

```
@"%@ has less than %i\uFF05 battery left!"
```

However, I'd still like to know why escaping doesn't work on a local notification.